# Accessing current google maps navigation on phone with arduino

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, arduino, arduino-ide

Hey i am pretty new to arduino but really learning a lot! This might be a little ambitious but i am looking to access navigation data on a android phone with arduino and then use this data for a output.

E.g when the google navigation says i am 100m from a left turn, i want to set an LED to high.

I assume i need a bluetooth shield to connect to the phone but i am unclear as to what else i would need to make this possible.

Any help would be a great help, i am at the deep end here so a little direction would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth would be great, yes. Making an Arduino and an Android communicate with BT is pretty easy. You can get really chez BT chips on eBay that works like a charm (I do that for my project).

Then you need to know exactly what kind of data you could get from the Android and how it is formated (JSON, XML, raw coordinates, something else?).

Do you know if you can get the data from directly from the Google Maps App on the phone?

What I would do (if it's possible, I'm not sure): rebuild some kind of GPS application which sends "markers" to the Arduino via bluetooth, i.e. when you're less than 100 meters away, it tells the Arduino to blink faster, if you took the wrong exit, it starts recalculating and tells the Arduino to blink red, something like that.

Is that what you intend to do? Or am I totally wrong? :)

Comment: Great thanks for the informative response! Nope your on the right track. Im pretty confident with connecting arduino to the phone via bluetooth as there seems to be lots of tutorials for this online. As you mentioned, i am totally lost with regard to getting the navigation data from the google maps application that comes pre-installed on android phones.

Comment: You're welcome! Connecting your Android phone and the Arduino via bt will be the easy part. The complexe part will be the kind of data you can transfer from the phone to the Arduino.